# Microsoft graph findmeetingtimes with meetingTimeSlot

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I pretty confuse about meetingTimeSlot attribute which returns from meetingTimeSuggestions

My activityDomain set to "work"  but my response code after I post to the API is

```
{ start:
   { dateTime: '2017-08-17T23:00:00.0000000',
     timeZone: 'SE Asia Standard Time' },
  end:
   { dateTime: '2017-08-18T01:00:00.0000000',
     timeZone: 'SE Asia Standard Time' } }
```

time length should around 8.00 am - 5.00 pm isn't it?

Here is my full code

```
 {
        "attendees": [{
            "type": "required", // First Attendee
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Pathompong Chaisri",
                "address": "T00400@g-able.com"
            }
        },  {
            "type": "required", // Third Attendee
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Artima C",
                "address": "Artima.C@g-able.com"
            }
        }],
        "locationConstraint": {
            "isRequired": "false",
            "suggestLocation": "false",
            "locations": [{
                "resolveAvailability": "false",
                "displayName": "KX Building Floor 13"
            }]
        },
        "timeConstraint": {
            "activityDomain": "work",
            "timeslots": [{
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2017-08-17T09:00:00",
                    "timeZone": "SE Asia Standard Time"
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2017-08-19T17:00:00",
                    "timeZone": "SE Asia Standard Time"
                }
            }]
        },
        "meetingDuration": "PT2H",
        "returnSuggestionReasons": "true",
        "minimumAttendeePercentage": "100"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that because your timeslot starts 17-08-2017 and ends two days later? I think you should provide separate 9-5 slots for each day.